# How to pass env variable to Gradle test via command line?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a standard java project layout and in some of my tests i have `System.getenv("my_var")`. I'd like to do run my tests using command line (from CI server) and pass the value of env var. Something like

```
./gradlew test -Dmy_var=xyz
```

but of course, this one doesn't work as tests are run by different jvm. so what's the exact command to pass the env var? i would prefer not to change my build scripts, create new tasks etc. i just want to pass env var via commandline. how can i do it?

Comment: You're going to *either* have to change your build script or change your test.  I personally would want to isolate where I'm using those environment variables and inject them instead, since `System.getenv` introduces state that's outside of your control normally.

Comment: Even with plain `java`, `-Dthis=that` sets a **system property** NOT an env var. AND it does so only if before (to the left of) the 'what-to-run' parameter (main class or module name or jar name, depending).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found it. as simple as:

```
my_var=xyz ./gradlew test
```